# Adding Associations dynamically from a selector in Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, dynamic, associations

I am a bit of a rails noob. I have a many to many relationship between QuestionGroups and Questions in a table called QuestionGroupQuestions, which belongs to QuestionGroups and Questions. In my QuestionGroups form, I have a selector to select a question and an "Add Question" button that dynamically stores an hidden input tag that stores each question selected. Sorta like this:

```
<input type="hidden" class="hidden_3" name="question_group_questions" value="3">
```

where value stores the question id. I want to submit all these hidden tags as an array to be inserted to the question_group_questions table.

How can I submit these hidden inputs as associations into the QuestionGroupQuestions table, using the QuestionGroup_id and the value of the hidden tag as the question_id ? Perhaps there is a simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Rails will create the necessary records when you provide an array of IDs for the relationship. To pass an array to Rails through a form add empty square brackets after the attribute name. In your instance it would look something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" class="hidden_3" name="question_group[question_ids][]" value="3"
```

Each of the hidden fields would have the same name, only the value would be unique for each one.